How to remap R_SHIFT to Up Arrow and Menu to Down Arrow on Ubuntu?
I recently move to ubuntu from win10, and my keyboard(Hator rockfall mecha tkl 2) software supporting only in win10, i used this software for remap key(R_SHIFT -> up_arrow; menu -> down_arrow) because i poured juice on her. and i learn programming that's i really need them.
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Up"
xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Down"

result:nothing
2.using xkb
create custom keymap
xkb_symbols "basic" {
    key <MENU> { [ Down ] };
    key <RTSH> { [ Up ] };
};

Added to the keymap:
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete" };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete" };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+custom(basic)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};

applied with
xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/custom $DISPLAY

result: many type errors
Warning:          Key <I708> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored

No symbols defined for <I248> (keycode 248)

and more
3. use key mapper
don't defined my keyboards
